# JavaScript add days not incrementing the month

Tags: javascript, getdate

I know this question has come up many times and I have used the recommended solution to created my function, but I have used it to scroll a calendar along the next/prev 4 weeks.

What seems to happen is that the first time it calculates d + 28 it is correct, but when the outputted result is used in the function it does not work.

Examples from console log:

Press 'next' first time:

```
start Before = Tue Jul 28 2015 21:53:20 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
start After = Tue Aug 25 2015 21:53:22 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Press 'next' a second time:

```
start Before = Tue Aug 25 2015 21:53:22 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
start After = Sat Aug 22 2015 21:53:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

and so it goes on.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="testApp">
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="testController">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input type="button" ng-click="prevWeeks(start)" value="subtract 28 days" ng-model="start" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="nextWeeks(start)" value="add 28 days" ng-model="start" />
  <hr />
  <div>{{start}}</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.start = new Date();

  $scope.nextWeeks = function(d) {
    console.log('Next:');
    console.log('  start Before = ' + d);
    $scope.start = addDays(d, 28);
    console.log('    start After = ' + $scope.start);
    console.log('\n');
    }

  $scope.prevWeeks = function(d) {
    console.log('Previous');
    console.log('  start Before = ' + d);
    $scope.start = addDays(d, -28);
    console.log('    start After = ' + d);
    console.log('\n');
  }

});

function addDays(d, qty) {
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
  var moreDate = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);

  var someDate = new Date();
  someDate.setDate(moreDate.getDate() + qty);

  return someDate;
}
```

On Plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/HQWx64MUAOIeXjKtKp8Y).

Any ideas? Have I slipped up somewhere?

Comment: I'm recommend to use moment.js library for this purpose!

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding and subtracting 1 from the month in `addDays`? When you use `setDate()`, it will automatically adjust the month if the date goes over the number of days in the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can be simplified greatly, because the `Date` type automatically takes care of adjusting the month when the date goes out of range.

```
function addDays(d, qty) {
    var dd = d.getDate();
    var mm = d.getMonth();
    var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    return new Date(yyyy, mm, dd + qty);
}
```

Another way would be:

```
function addDays(d, qty) {
    var newDate = new Date(d.getTime()); // Copy date
    newDate.setDate(d.getDate() + qty);
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. I see what I was doing wrong, so appreciate everyone's understanding and help.

Answer (score 1):

Since ways to fix this has already been provided let me tell you why your way doesn't work. You first create `moreDate` which adjusts the year and month to the intended values but after that you create `someDate` which is initialized as the current day with current month and current year. You add `qty` to the date and set that on `someDate`. The calculation then is relative to today and not relative to the date provided as argument. For example,

```
var d = new Date(); //July 28 2015
d = addDays(d,28); //Aug 25 2015,works because we added 28 days to today
d = addDays(d,28); //Aug 22 2015!! Looks wrong, but is it?
```

The last call clearly looks wrong but it isn't really. Stepping through your code:

```
  /*more code*/
  var moreDate = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd); //Aug 25 2015

  var someDate = new Date(); //Catch!! July 28 2015
  someDate.setDate(moreDate.getDate() + qty); //Catch!!
  //the call above added 28+25 days to today which is Aug 22 2015
  return someDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean to just initialise someDate for use.